# Make sure two regexes not find the same results

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse out all dates (possibly written in different forms) from a string. The problem is that  there could be a date written in this form `d/m -y` for example 22/11 -12. But there could also be a date written in this form `d/m` with no year specified. If I find a date in this string which contains the longer form, I don't want it to be found again in the shorter form. This is where my code fails, it finds the first date twice (one time with the year, and one time without it).

I really have two questions: (1) What is the "right" way of doing this. It really seems that I coming at this problem from the wrong angle. (2) If I should stick to this way of doing this, how comes that this line `datestring.replace(match.group(0), '')` don't remove the date so I could'nt be found again?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

dformats = (
    '(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2}) -(?P<year>\d{2})',
    '(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})',
    '(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})',
            )


def get_dates(datestring):
    """Try to extract all dates from certain strings.

    Arguments:
    - `datestring`: A string containing dates.
    """
    global dformats

    found_dates = []

    for regex in dformats:
        matches = re.finditer(regex, datestring)
        for match in matches:
            # Is supposed to make sure the same date is not found twice
            datestring.replace(match.group(0), '')

            found_dates.append(match)
    return found_dates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = get_dates('1/2 -13, 5/3 & 2012-11-22')
    for date in dates:
        print date.groups()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use a single regular expression and use the | operator to join all your cases together:

   `expr = re.compile ( r"expr1|expr2|expr3" )`
2. Find only single instances, and then pass a "start position" for the next search. Note that this will complicate things, since you want to always start with the earliest match, no matter which format is chosen. Ie, loop through all three matches, figure out which is the earliest match, do the replacement, then do it again with a incremented start position. This makes option 1 much easier regardless.

A few additional points:

1. Make sure you're using "raw strings": prepend an 'r' at the front of each of the strings. Otherwise the '\' characters risk getting eaten up and not passed to the RE engine
2. Consider using "sub" and a callback function in place of the "repl" parameter to do the replacement, rather than finditer. "repl" in this case is passed a match object, and should return the replacement string.
3. Matching groups in your "single" re will have the value None if that alternative was not chosen, making it easy to detect which alternate was used.
4. You should not say "global" unless you intend to modify that variable.

Here's some complete, working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

expr = re.compile(
    r'(?P<day1>\d{1,2})/(?P<month1>\d{1,2}) -(?P<year>\d{2})|(?P<day2>\d{1,2})/(?P<month2>\d{1,2})|(?P<year3>\d{4})-(?P<month3>\d{2})-(?P<day3>\d{2})')


def get_dates(datestring):
    """Try to extract all dates from certain strings.

    Arguments:
    - `datestring`: A string containing dates.
    """

    found_dates = []
    matches = expr.finditer(datestring)
    for match in matches:
        if match.group('day1'):
            found_dates.append({'day': match.group('day1'),
                                 'month': match.group('month1') })
        elif match.group('day2'):
            found_dates.append({'day': match.group('day2'),
                                'month': match.group('month2')})
        elif match.group('day3'):
            found_dates.append({'day': match.group('day3'),
                                'month': match.group('month3'),
                                'year': match.group('year3')})
        else:
            raise Exception("wtf?")
    return found_dates

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dates = get_dates('1/2 -13, 5/3 & 2012-11-22')
    for date in dates:
        print date
```

Comment: Emacs complained you don't follow pep-8 ;-) Otherwise a good answer.  I bothers me though that it is'nt a simpler way of dealing with the same names of groups when using `|` in a regex. There is like 6 lines dealing with that problem(!) :-/

Comment: Niclas: Yeah, I edited it about 3 times and probably still didn't get it right :) Also, yes, I was frustrated that the RE engine didn't let me re-use the names, I could probably create a simple function to do remapping to tidy the code. If we can assume that we always copy PERIOD-X to PERIOD, if dayX exists, for X in range(1,4),  and PERIOD in ['day','month','year'] then that would just be a couple of lines. Any more complex processing would probably have to break it out like above.

Comment: @ChrisCogdon Yeah, that is what you had to do if you used a lot of regexes (and not only three as I am)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `negative look ahead` in your 2nd regex to match only those `dates` which are not followed by `-year`: -

```
dformats = (
    r'(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2}) -(?P<year>\d{2})',
    r'(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})(?!\s+-(?P<year>\d{2}))',
    r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})'
)
```

Thus, the dates which are matched in the `first` Regex, will not be matched in the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sub` instead of `find`:

```
def find_dates(s):

    dformats = (
        '(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2}) -(?P<year>\d{2})',
        '(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})',
        '(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})',
    )    

    dates = []
    for f in dformats:
        s = re.sub(f, lambda m: dates.append(m.groupdict()), s)
    return dates
```